edge line drawn over node image/shape in Pyvis
When using image as shape, edges are drawn to the center of the node's shape (image) obstructing it. I'd like to have Node shapes 'on top' of the edge lines hiding them or edges been drawn to the border of the shape/image rather than center.
Cannot find clues in the Pyvis documentation.
